# Is it possible to use Sass variables in the comments?

Tags: sass

I've defined a variable called `$col-num: 12` in the SCSS file, and I want to show the value inside the comments. I tried both `/*$col-num*/` and `/*#{$col-num}*/`, but they were neither working. What I want is just `/*12*/`. Is it possible to parse Sass variables inside the comments?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try to add a `!` at the begin of your comment

```
/*! #{$col-num} */
```

From http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#comments

> When the first letter of a comment is !, the comment will be **interpolated** and always rendered into css output even in compressed output modes. This is useful for adding Copyright notices to your generated CSS.